# Undefined Property: Security::$table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Recently I've been trying to get data from a model that is associated to my current model through another association. This is specifically the code I'm referring to:

```
$this->Portfolio->Security->find('first' array(data));
```

I am calling this from Transaction.php. This is throwing the error listed in the title. I'm also getting a second error below that, "Call to undefined method Security::find()"

I have my associations set up as such:

Transaction.php

```
public $belongsTo = array('Portfolio', 'Ticker');
```

Portfolio.php

```
public $hasMany = array('Transaction', 'Security', 'Account');
```

Security.php

```
public $belongsTo = array('Portfolio', 'Ticker');
```

I've also tried calling a function in Portfolio, such as:

```
$this->Portfolio->getSecurites();
```

Which would then call the find method in Security:

```
$this->Security->find('first', array(data));
```

But that also fails in the same manner. My table for security is created and is called "securities", with the fields "id", "portfolio_id", "ticker_id", and a few others that should be inconsequential.

Comment: CakePHP has a utility that is already named `Security`. Using that in your table is `dangerous` as they will collide and the `Core` one will win.. :) .. I would suggested changing `Security` to something else. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html

Comment: @AndreSantiago That's exactly what it was, thanks for your help. If you could add this as an answer below I would happily accept it.

Comment: Tai`Roth.. I am glad it helped. Question is marked as duplicate which can no longer be opened for answer.. but is alright...